# Prohibit resolving during loading in typesafe config

Tags: java, scala, typesafe-config

I want to prohibit resolving of `a.b`. I want to substitute `param` from another config. Like this:

```
val d = ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseString(
    """
      |param = x
      |a.b = ${param}
    """.stripMargin))

val a = ConfigFactory.parseString("param = 1")

val result = a.withFallback(d).resolve()
```

In this case `param` gets value 1, but `a.b` remains `x`
I've tried to set `ConfigResolveOptions.defaults().setAllowUnresolved(true)` when loading config `d`, but that doesn't work.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround for my problem:

So If I have config file `application.conf` which uses `include` to include config files which contain substitution syntax and files which contain declaration of the config values which are going to be substituted.

```
val a = ConfigFactory.parseString(s"""param = 1""")
 val z = ConfigFactory.parseResources("application.conf") //this doesn't resolve substitutions

val result = a.withFallback(z).resolve().withFallback(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
```

Comment: The problem, which I pointed out, was the fact that `Config.load` was resolving the substitutions.  So that was the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `Config.load` is resolving the substitution immediately.  If you take that out it resolves like you want it to:

```
val p = ConfigFactory.parseString(
  """
    |param = x
    |a.b = ${param}
  """.stripMargin)

val a = ConfigFactory.parseString("param = 1")

val result = a.withFallback(p).resolve()

println(result.getString("a.b"))
```

This prints 1.

You don't need to use `Config.load` unless you want to use `reference.conf`, etc.  If you do want to use `Config.load` then you should do it after you have composed all the configs together using `withFallback`.

For example, this also prints 1:

```
  val p = ConfigFactory.parseString(
    """
      |param = x
      |a.b = ${param}
    """.stripMargin)

  val d = ConfigFactory.load(p)
  val a = ConfigFactory.parseString("param = 1")

  val result = a.withFallback(p)
  val loaded = ConfigFactory.load(result)
  println(loaded.getString("a.b"))
```

Or, say you have an `application.conf` with `include` that you want to use with `ConfigFactory.load()` (per your comment).

If `application.conf` looks like

```
include "foo"
```

and `foo.conf` looks like

```
a.b = ${param}
```

then this prints 1 also:

```
  val a = ConfigFactory.parseString("param = 1")  

  val app = ConfigFactory.load("application", ConfigParseOptions.defaults,
    ConfigResolveOptions.defaults.setAllowUnresolved(true))

  val result = a.withFallback(app).resolve

  println(result.getString("a.b"))
```

In general, if you want A to override B to override C then you should use `A.withFallback(B).withFallback(C)`.

Comment: That's also a good point, but with load I just load my main `application.conf` which has a lot of imports and that `param` config value is used in several places in different config files(Actually it is declared with some stub value on one of them and is used in others). If I create `Config` object with with some of parse methods avaialbale they just parse the content that is in application.conf and ignore all imports

Comment: Perhaps time to submit a pull request to typesafe?

Comment: Do you mean include (not import)?  Your example did not use `application.conf`.   I've updated my answer to handle what I think you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled a bit with the same thing: trying to use "fallbacks" to override values, when it was designed for layering/merging configs

Assuming I understand your use case, I recommend instead using file includes.

In my `application.conf` I have the default value

```
a.b = "placeholder"
```

And at the bottom I have the following include

```
# Local overrides - for development use
include "local.conf"
```

And finally in `local.conf`

```
param = 1
a.b = ${param}
```

The end result is that `a.b` will be overridden with `1`

Comment: It's good example, but what if param = 1 isn't static value. What if it is calculated at runtime(at startup of the application)?

Comment: "[Put] some logic in code instead of building up values in the config itself." https://github.com/typesafehub/config#note-about-resolving-substitutions-in-referenceconf-and-applicationconf

Comment: My real case is to override the value of spay's `host-connector.max-conections` and override max paralleism of one of the akka's dispatcher's executor to the number of available processors on a machine.

Comment: I understand. "Fallback" does not seem to work quite like that, so this is what I had to do.